# intent.createchooser not working on Android 12 (Api 31)

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to always show the application selection dialog always if there are multiple possible options. Even if there is a default application for this action. I am trying to run a url that opens banking applications. Here is my code

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("ACTION_VIEW");
intent.setData(Uri.parse("myPaymentUrl"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "My title"));
```

It fully works on Android 11, but it doesn't work on Android 12 (Api 31). When I run the code, one application is launched instantly, without select additional options

P.S. I also need to not show browser applications, but only bank applications. I am trying use setFlags, but it is not working

```
intent.setFlags(1024);//FLAG_ACTIVITY_REQUIRE_NON_BROWSER
```

Comment: Did you see this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/183035750 ? That seems rather weird but maybe that's the intended behavior

Comment: If you dont show how your url looks like then how do you think we can help you? How should we know which apps should be choosable by the user?

Comment: You should not only set an uri but also a mime type.